# Postgresql 9.4: Deleting a row from a table and it's linkages from other tables and getting all the deleted rows in response

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a database with around 20 normalized tables and there are a lot of foreign key constraints between these tables. The user table for instance, is being referenced in 3 other tables and the primary keys of these 3 tables are further referenced in other tables whose primary keys are further referenced in other tables.

Now, I need to implement a functionality for archiving a user which involves deleting the row from user table and deleting all its direct and indirect linkages, but at the same time saving, serializing everything in a JSON structure and dumping it in an `archive` table so that if the need arises to unarchive the user in future, we can do that. I was thinking of writing a function for this since it makes a lot more sense to do this entire activity in a single transaction. I was wondering if there is a better and easier alternative for doing such thing ?

Comment: Use triggers. Search for "postgreSQL audit trigger".

Comment: That looks very clean. Thanks. One question though. If I create audit triggers for all the tables which are directly/indirectly linked to my user table and log all the DELETE operations in their respective tables, is there any way I can assign an identifier to the entire deletion operation using which I can quickly identify all the deletes which belong to a single API call in my application ?

Comment: You can do it for the whole transaction or subtransaction using `txid_current()` I guess. There isn't really a statement-level equivalent.